# Purpose of isLoaded on jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the below jQuery code in my `start.js` file. My question is could anyone tell me what the `isLoaded: !!(window.jQuery && jQuery.cookie)` code segment does?

```
Sys.loader.defineScripts(
    {
        releaseUrl: '~/scripts/jquery/{0}/jquery.{0}.min.js',
        debugUrl: '~/scripts/jquery/{0}/jquery.{0}.js'
    }, 
    [
        { name: 'blockUI', dependencies: ['jQueryUI'], isLoaded: !!(window.jQuery && jQuery.blockUI) },
        { name: 'rating', dependencies: ['jQuery'], isLoaded: !!(window.jQuery && jQuery.rating) },
        { name: 'watermark', dependencies: ['jQuery'], isLoaded: !!(window.jQuery && jQuery.fn.watermark) },
        { name: 'mousewheel', dependencies: ['jQuery'], isLoaded: !!(window.jQuery && jQuery.event.special.mousewheel) },
        { name: 'cookie', dependencies: ['jQuery'], isLoaded: !!(window.jQuery && jQuery.cookie) },
        { name: 'tmpl', dependencies: ['jQuery'], isLoaded: !!(window.jQuery && jQuery.fn.tmpl) },
        { name: 'maskedinput', dependencies: ['jQuery'], isLoaded: !!(window.jQuery && jQuery.fn.maskedinput) },
        { name: 'ba-bbq', dependencies: ['jQuery'], isLoaded: !!(window.jQuery && jQuery.bbq) },
        { name: 'validate', dependencies: ['jQuery'], isLoaded: !!(window.jQuery && jQuery.fn.validate) },
        { name: 'form', dependencies: ['jQuery'], isLoaded: !!(window.jQuery && jQuery.fn.ajaxForm) },
    ]
);
```

Comment: It converts anything to boolean

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I don't know some one who changed my question. My question is what does "isLoaded" do on above code snippet ?

Answer (score 0):

`!!` always retrun boolean value. either `true` or `false`.

In some languages `nil` or `false` consider as `false` in boolean expression and everything else is consider as `true` for boolean expression.

but in order to get boolean true/false you can use `!!`

Comment: Do you have any idea about the meaning of "isLoaded" ?